# How to fix this small bug of displaying smileys in chat, and replacing swears with asterisks in chat?

Tags: php, parsing

Hey all so I have a chat box for my site and there was already a smileys feature built into it, however there was no "curse filter" so I decided I would try and add that today. This is the output of the chat box:

```
$return .= "<div style=\"font-size: 14px; padding-bottom: 3px; color: #444444;\">". $time     . $icon . $username . str_replace('"', "'", parse_bbcode(smiley(str_replace("\n", '',     $chat['text'])))) ."</div>";
```

Near the end of that it shows:

```
str_replace('"', "'", parse_bbcode(smiley(str_replace("\n", '',     $chat['text']))))
```

I have replaced smiley with curses just to test it out, and the curses function works perfectly, but I'm wondering how I can get both the smiley AND curses functions to display, instead of just one or the other.

I've tried:

```
parse_bbcode(smiley, curses
parse_bbcode(smiley . curses
```

but have had no luck....

Here is my parse_bbcode function:

```
function parse_bbcode($text, $xhtml = true) {
        $tags = array(
                '#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<strong>\\1</strong>' : '<b>\\1</b>'),
                '#\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<em>\\1</em>' : '<i>\\1</i>'),
                '#\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">\\1</span>' : '<u>\\1</u>'),
                '#\[s\](.*?)\[/s\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<strike>\\1</strike>' : '<s>\\1</s>'),
                '#\[color=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/color\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<span style="color: \\1;">\\2</span>' : '<font color="\\1">\\2</font>'),
                '#\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<img src="\\1" border="0" alt="" style="max-width: 400px; max-height: 200px;" />' : '<img src="\\1" border="0" alt="">'),
                '#\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]#si' => '<a href="\\1" target="_blank" style="color: #000000; font-size: 12px;" title="\\2">\\2</a>',
                '#\[email\](.*?)\[/email\]#si' => '<a href="mailto:\\1" title="Email \\1">\\1</a>',
                '#\[code\](.*?)\[/code\]#si' => '<code>\\1</code>',
                '#\[align=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/align\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<div style="text-align: \\1;">\\2</div>' : '<div align="\\1">\\2</div>'),
                '#\[br\]#si' => ($xhtml ? '<br style="clear: both;" />' : '<br>'),
        );

        foreach ($tags AS $search => $replace) {
                $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $text);
        }

        return $text;
}
```

Comment: I need to know: did you make your own swear filter or use pre-existing a library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my...

```
... parse_bbcode(curses(smiley(...
```

Comment: thanks, I'm sorry, I'm pretty much just starting out with PHP and didn't look at any of those "basic" tutorials